# Add pseudo class with jquery on DIV

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have a pseudo class / element defined:

```
.editableDiv:empty:not(:focus)::before{
        content:attr(data-text);
        color: #CCC;
        font-style: italic;
        margin-left: 5px;        
    }

.editableDiv {
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
    -moz-user-modify: read-write;
    user-modify: read-write;    
}
```

With this, I am getting placeholder like functionality on DIV element. Everything works fine. But, I am adding my DIV's dynamically. With dynamic change to DOM, those rules are not applied. How can I apply those rules on dynamically added elements with jQuery? Is it possible to translate those rules (placeholder functionality on DIV) in a pure CSS?

**EDIT:**

[Link to code pen project where I have this problem](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/oLoxzz)

Problem solved here:

[Link to solved problem](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/kXxLVW)

Comment: Why would you not use `data` tags or classes? They can be set and unset by JQuery and read by CSS no matter how dynamic.

Comment: I didn't know for that. Do you have any example?

Comment: It depends on how you are adding the elements to the DOM....I'm sure this has come up before.

Comment: Do you mean css rules? post a jsfiddle...

Comment: I've added link to code pen project.